# "You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using the Parse library" error in a closed app (Android)

Tags: android, parse-platform

I get this error toast whenever my app is not running:

> You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey)
>   before using the Parse library

I call Parse.initialize when the user logs in. Is there a way not to start parse every time I turn on the device? Is stopping parse service possible?

Thank you very much

Comment: Protect any external path into parts of your code which use this library with a check to be sure that you have initialized or logged in.  If you haven't, either do that, fire an intent to your log in activity, or simply finish() what may be an undesired resume of an Activity or Service that shouldn't be running on its own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  import com.parse.Parse;
    import android.app.Application;

    public class App extends Application {
      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
      }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:name="yourpackagename.App"
.
.
.
</application>
```

Comment: great answer! I needed to remove this line though "Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);"

Answer (score 3):

Any Variable if you want to use in all your application activity or fragment. you can use Application class.

**What is Application Class?**

As Per developer docs

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state.
>   You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your
>   AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, which will cause that class
>   to  be instantiated for you when the process for your
>   application/package is created.

so Initialize Parse object in Application class. as mustafaasgvi answer.

and add this class in Application Tag of your ProjectMeanifeast file as this way.

```
<application
        android:name="YourPackageName.App"
</application>
```