# Runtime Exception:An error occurred while executing doInBackground at Activity

Tags: android

I am getting this runtime error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground() . applicationContext is null. You must
>   call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using
>   the Parse library.

While I am clicking the settings icon,the application throws the runtime error like these.

I am posted the codes and pointed out the error line below:

**StackTrace:**

```
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323): Process: com.qrme.quranmadeeasy, PID: 3323
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using the Parse library.
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at com.parse.Parse.checkContext(Parse.java:518)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at com.parse.Parse.getParseDir(Parse.java:235)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at com.parse.ParseObject.getDiskObject(ParseObject.java:382)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at com.parse.ParseObject.getFromDisk(ParseObject.java:486)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at com.parse.ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation(ParseInstallation.java:78)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at com.qrme.quranmadeeasy.SettingsActivity.refreshUserProfile(SettingsActivity.java:485)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at com.qrme.quranmadeeasy.SettingsActivity.access$0(SettingsActivity.java:484)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at com.qrme.quranmadeeasy.SettingsActivity$checkforupdate.doInBackground(SettingsActivity.java:629)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at com.qrme.quranmadeeasy.SettingsActivity$checkforupdate.doInBackground(SettingsActivity.java:1)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-27 08:43:32.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3323):     ... 4 more
```

**SettingsActivity.java:**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
static ProgressDialog pd;

    Dialog dialog;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    }

........
........

private void refreshUserProfile() { --->484th line
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().refreshInBackground(  --->485th line
                new RefreshCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {

                        if (e == null) {

                            displayUserProfile();

                        }  
                    }
                });
    }

    public class checkforupdate extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            refreshUserProfile();   ---->629th line

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // pd.dismiss();
            // finish();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call

```
  Parse.initialize(context, PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
```

in your `Application` or in `Activity`

For more info refer this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750794/you-must-call-parse-initializecontext-applicationid-clientkey-before-using)

Comment: let me know where I have to call this?

Comment: @Naruto try suggested link

Comment: Thank you very much once again :)

Answer (score 1):

> You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey)
>   before using the Parse library.

Means you are not calling `initialize` with application context, app_key and clientkey in `Application` class.

To use `Parse` library in project you need to add `Application` class in project and in `onCreate` method of `Application` class call `initialize` method of Parse` library before calling other methods :

```
// Initialize the Parse SDK.
  Parse.initialize(this, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
```

See [Android’s Application Class](http://androidexample.com/Global_Variable_Or_Application_Context_Variable_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=114&aaid=136) example to add `Application` class in project